# Call application process from page in oracle apex

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have a page in my apex application, that displays an interactive report.
Top of region, i have 2 buttons, 1 is for adding a new row, 2nd is for downloading the report.

I have an application level process "DOWNLOAD_USER_LIST", that downloads the report in excel format.
when i am calling this process via Download button click DA in my page it does nothing, just submits the page.

below is the DA action:

**type**: javascript expression

**code**
apex.submit( {
request: "DOWNLOAD_USER_LIST",
showWait: true,
validate: true
} );

my application level process has the condition:

**Request = Expression 1**

**Expression 1 = DOWNLOAD_USER_LIST**

what am i missing..?

*Also the same approach works on other pages, just not this one.*

Comment: If you have pages that work properly, did you **compare** every (significant) property? When you said that button "just submits the page", it looks as if button action isn't set to *dynamic action*, but to default *page submit*. If that isn't it, run the page in debug mode to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

That code does not invoke the application process, it just submits the page with *request value* DOWNLOAD_USER_LIST. To invoke an application process, you need to call `apex.server.process`. I'm curious to know *how* you're invoking this process on the other pages where you say it works.

Comment: In all the other pages, the report require some filters, so i am opening a modal then user selects the filters and clicks download and Voila..!! it works..!!   but not for this report.

Comment: "The user clicks" doesn't explain how you implemented this. What happens when the user clicks download. Is it a dynamic action ? A page process ?

Comment: this is done via dynamic action:   

type: javascript expression

code apex.submit( { request: "name_of_other_process", showWait: true, validate: true } );

Comment: Well... in that case I'd suggest debug. You say it works for one page, not for the other, so debug both pages and look for differences. Not sure there is much we can do for you.

Comment: Can you help me with ajax callback. I want to call application process using ajax in my page. what steps should i follow.

Comment: Google "oracle apex ajax callback example", there are are many nicely written out examples. I'm not sure you can invoke a download process via callback though - I'd think it has to go in a page process instead.